# Проблема парсинга ods файла

Tags: java, xml

Использую библиотеку jopendocument (http://www.jopendocument.org) для чтения данных из ods файла. Когда беру количество колонок и строк для листа он выдает 1024 и 1048576 соответственно, хотя в файле, по существу, всего 3 строки и несколько колонок. В api для этой библиотеки я не нашел других методов, кроме как getRowCount и getColumnCount. Глянул структуру файла, xml-ку, там немного строк.

Какие вижу варианты развития событий:
1. Смена библиотеки для парсинга ods.
Вопрос в том, на что сменить. Ничего достойного не нашел.
2. Самостоятельно парсить xml-ку.
Не самое лучшее решение. Хотелось бы использовать что-то готовое.
3. Самые идеальный вариант - универсальная библиотека для работы с xls, xlsx, ods файлами.
Искал в сети, находил только платные варианты.

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной проблемой? Что можете подсказать, в каком направлении лучше двигаться?